# Cordova - IOS - Is there any way to open WIFI setting or Mobile Data settings directly?

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, wifi, settings

English is my second language. I apologize.

I'm trying to develop an hybrid app and it needs wifi or mobile data enabled to work.

If none of them are enables a Pop-Up appears and gives the user 3 options, Wifi, Mobile Data or cancel.

On Android there's no problem. I can use cordova's diagnostic plugin and use switchToWifiSettings() or switchToMobileDataSettings()

But for IOS only switchToSettings() is available. Is there any way to go further and open WIFI settings or Mobile Data directly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality was removed in iOS 5.1. There's no way to go further than that.